# Can someone explain the mathematics behind this solution

Tags: ruby, algorithm, range

A question asks:

- Take a sequence of numbers from 1 to n (where n > 0).
- Within that sequence, there are two numbers, a and b.
- The product of a and b should equal the sum of all numbers in the sequence excluding a and b.
- Given a number n, could you tell me the numbers excluded from the sequence?

My plan was to get the sum of the range, then create an array using the combination enumerator to get all of the possible pairs of the range, then check if the product of the pair equals the sum of the range minus the sum of the pair. This solution worked, but took way too long:

```
def removNb(n)
  arr = [*1..n]
  sum = arr.inject(:+) 
  ab = []

  [*(n/2)..n].combination(2).to_a.each do |pair|
    if pair.inject(:*) == sum - pair.inject(:+) 
        ab << pair 
        ab << [pair[1],pair[0]]
    end 
  end
  ab
end
```

Here is a solution that I found:

```
def removNb(n)
  res = []
  total = (n*n + n) / 2 
  range = (1..n)

  (1..n).each do |a|
    b = ((total - a) / (a * 1.0 + 1.0))
     if b == b.to_i && b <= n
      res.push([a,b.to_i])

    end
  end
  return res
end
```

but can't understand how it works. I understand the equation behind the total.

Answer (score 4):

You could form a equation

> a * b = (sum of sequence from 1 to n) - (a + b)

from this statement

> the **product of a and b** should be **equal to** the **sum of all numbers** in
>   the sequence, **excluding a and b**

sum of sequence from 1 to n (denote as total) = n(n+1)/2 = (n*n + n) / 2

Reorder above equation, you get

> b = (total - a) / (a + 1)

The remaining work is to test if there exist integer a and b matching this equation

Comment: right its a simple algebra i cant believe i didn't see that thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code returns an array of all pairs of numbers in the sequence that have the desired property. Let's step through it.

Initialize the array to be returned.

```
res = []
```

Compute the sum of the elements in the sequence. The sum of the elements of any arithmetic sequence equals the first element plus the last element, multiplied by the number of elements in the sequence, the product divided by 2. Here that is `total = n*(1+n)/2`, which can be expressed as

```
total = (n*n + n) / 2
```

`range = (1..n)` is unnecessary as `range` is not subsequently referenced.

Loop through the elements of the sequence

```
(1..n).each do |a|
```

For each value of `a` we seek another element of the sequence `b` such that

```
a*b = total - a - b
```

Solving for `b`:

```
b = (total - a)/ (a * 1.0 + 1.0)
```

If `b` is in the range, save the pair `[a, b]`

```
if b == b.to_i && b <= n
  res.push([a,b.to_i])
end
```

Return the array `res`

```
res
```

This method contains two errors:

- If `[a,b]` is added to `res`, it will be added twice
- `[a,a]` could be added to `res` (such as `n=5`, `a=b=3`)

I would write this as follows.

```
def remove_numbers(n)
  total = n*(n+1)/2 
  (1..n-1).each_with_object([]) do |a,res|
    next unless (total-a) % (a+1) == 0
    b = (total-a)/(a+1)
    res << [a,b] if (a+1..n).cover?(b)
  end
end
```

For example,

```
remove_numbers 10
  #=> [[6, 7]]
remove_numbers 1000
  #=> []
```

Out of cursiosity:

```
(2..10_000).map { |x| [x, remove_numbers(x).size] }.max_by(&:last)
  #=> [3482, 4]
remove_numbers 3482
  #=> [[1770, 3423], [2023, 2995], [2353, 2575], [2460, 2463]]
```